# Libgdx scene2d for 3D game with 2D logic?

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx, scene2d

I started a 2D top down game with libgdx scene2d and i like how it is implemented, its logic and how the programmers can use it (for example `stage.act()` calls `actor.act(delta)` for every registred `Actor`). Now i thoguht about using this logic for a 3D game. I know that scene2d is mainly made for UI and not for games at all, especially not for 3D. But my 3D games logic would be like 2D top down.
Let me explain: You, the player, are in a maze. You can only collide with the walls, which are the same on every height. So the collision detection would be the same as in 2D top down. Also you cannot jump, only walk forward, backward... so also movement would be the same as 2D topdown. Only the view, so the drawing, would be first person, so 3D. Would it be to bad to abuse scene2d for the logic only and use `Model` and so on for the 3D drawing? I just thought using scene2d, so i don't have to write my own "all registered objects act now" methods. What do you think about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use scene2d in this case, if you want to catch input events on your Actors, for example mouse clicks.

That's actually one of the main uses for scene2d (and why it's used mostly for UI). Another reason is the ability to group actors, but I think you wouldn't need that.

If you do not want to catch input events on your game objects, then you should not use scene2d.

Simulating what scene2d's `Stage` does is as easy as maintaining a `List<Entity>` and calling `entity.update(delta)` (equivalent to stage.act()) and `entity.render(delta)` (equivalent to stage.draw()) on each entity in the list.

Comment: So it would be easier to manage this on my own instead of using scene2d?

Comment: In case you do not want to click on your "actors", yes. Otherwise scene2d could be useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I hope i am able to do a simple 3D game xD +1